# Is it possible to pass a variable to 'get_search_form()' in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, templatetags

I've tried to read the official docs but I can't find this information.

I'm developing a custom Wordpress theme, and I have created a search form in the `searchform.php` file, which is called by using the `get_search_form()` template tag.

I'm using the same form on multiple locations on my theme; it has the same design, the same fields, and so on, it should only differ for a single value that I wish to pass as a variable when calling it with `get_search_form()`.

Is it possible to do so? And if not possible, what could be the best way to accomplish this, without having to duplicate a whole `.php` file just to have a single value to be different?

Comment: The filter `search_form_args` gets executed by `get_search_form`, so you could probably use that to add additional arguments to the array at that point.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think you could pass optional arg (preferably an array) to <strike>`get_search_form()` like so</strike>
<strike>`get_search_form($options)`.</strike>
Inside the function you could do something like:</strike>

Seems that the only reasonable thing to do is to hook to the function. Check out this post: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/

or else you could create a $_SESSION variable or a cookie where you would store desired value. Depending on location, the value would change and you would end up with a sample form looking something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
    <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['your_value'])) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="additional_parameter" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['your_value']; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there some documentation about this? To my knowledge, the only arguments could be 'echo' and 'aria_label'

Comment: `get_search_form` is an already existing WP function, not a self-written one that could be modified at will.

Comment: yup, i misunderstood your question

check this out though - you can hook to the function using `add_filter`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/